# extract string in R using regex for a variable number of instances

Tags: r, regex, variables

I've got a string column (data.table) that I need to parse based on a pattern (text between '-' ) and a defined (but variable) number of instances of that pattern and I'm not sure how to do it using regex:

```
> test <- c("AAA-bb-ccc", "abcd-efgh","blah", "blah-blah-blah-blah")
```

say, the predefined number of instances is i.

```
> i = 1
> output
"AAA"  "abcd"  "blah"  "blah

> i = 2
> output
"bb"  "efgh"  ""  "blah"


> i= 3
> output
"ccc"  ""  ""  "blah"
```

how would i use a general regex using i that would achieve this?

Comment: You probably just need to split the string and get the `i - 1`th element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `i=3` you can try

```
unlist(lapply(strsplit(test,split = '-'),'[',3)) 
[1] "ccc"  NA     NA     "blah"
```

Comment: thanks, this is perfect as I can use it in my data.table. So, there is no clean way to do this using regex?

Comment: @Ankhnesmerira, unfortunately, I'm not aware of any regex. But maybe with crazy regex grouping.

Answer (score 1):

We can create a function which splits on "-" and returns the ith value.

```
get_i_th_element <- function(test, i) {
   sapply(strsplit(test, "-"), function(x) if(length(x) >= i) x[[i]] else "")
}

get_i_th_element(test, 1)
#[1] "AAA"  "abcd" "blah" "blah"

get_i_th_element(test, 3)
#[1] "ccc"  ""     ""     "blah"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `tokenize_regex` from the `tokenizers` package and then `data.table::transpose` and `cbind` relevant columns into a `data.table`

```
test <- c("AAA-bb-ccc", "abcd-efgh","blah", "blah-blah-blah-blah")

library(tokenizers)
library(data.table)
test <- transpose(tokenize_regex(test, "-"), fill = "")

i <- 1:3
as.data.table(do.call(cbind, test[i]))
#     V1   V2   V3
#1:  AAA   bb  ccc
#2: abcd efgh
#3: blah
#4: blah blah blah
```